# Parse server : Update multiple rows/Objects by REST API

Tags: rest, parse-platform

In parse server, have to update multiple rows of the a table by **REST API** Is there anyway I can achieve this instead of looping the record and update each of them.

Comment: I guess you can define a function in the cloud code to perform your complex job: `Parse.Cloud.define`

Comment: @Etgar Thanks Brother.

Comment: You're welcome. Added an answer.

Answer (score 0):

You're better off using [Batch Operations](https://parseplatform.github.io/docs/rest/guide/#batch-operations).

Comment: Would like to know why a down vote for an advice on what to use... which is meant to be used in this use case.

Answer (score 0):

You can define a function in the cloud code to perform your service: `Parse.Cloud.define`

Comment: This is a bad idea to do, because you are proxying requests to Cloud Code, so your client endpoint sends request to Cloud Code, and that does a Rest API Batch Operation... It is possible to use Batch Operations directly from Client. Also lacking an example.